# javascript date format not supported - need the format anyway

Tags: javascript, date, format

I need to compare dates but the finnish date format does not seem to be supported (thanks javascript!).

Here is the code that should return the difference between 2 dates (one of them being today):

```
function jämförMedIdag (datum) {
    if (datum == null || datum == "") {
        alert('Inget datum!');
        return;
    }
    var datum = new Date(datum);
    var dagar = datum.getDate();
    var månader = datum.getMonth();
    var år = datum.getYear();
    var nyttDatum = new Date();
    nyttDatum.setFullYear(år,månader,dagar);
    var idag = new Date();

    if(nyttDatum>idag) {
        var svar = nyttDatum - idag;
        return(svar);
    } else {
        var svar = idag - nyttDatum;
        return(svar);
    }
}
```

How can I tell javascript that my date is in format dd.mm.yyyy or d.m.yyyy or dd.m.yyyy or d.mm.yyyy?

Comment: @bjornd egen funktion, eget språk ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write a parser from scratch you can give a try to [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), an open source library which has 150+ localized plugins. There's a Finnish version too.

Comment: Judging by the quick demo on their website - Thats just brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

There is no function like `strptime` in JavaScript, so you'll have to parse it yourself by using string manipulation functions like `split` or `match`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those functions, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just parse it yourself:

```
var parts = datum.split('.');
datum = new Date();
datum.setFullYear(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
```

Etc.